# Linq Entity With Return Function

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have 2 tables:

- `Room_Type`  (***ID_Room_Type***, Name_Room_Type)
- `Room_Room` (***ID_Room_Type***, Number_Room)

How to place a new column `Temp` in the `RoomType` table that will take its value as the sum of the rooms from the `Room_Room` table.

**This code does not work :**

```
Private Sub SimpleButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SimpleButton1.Click

    Dim Db As New HotelEntities

    Dim s = (From I In Db.Room_Type Select I.ID_Room_Type, I.Name_Room_Type, ColumnTemp = GetTotal_Room(I.ID_Room_Type)).ToList()

    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = s

End Sub

Private Function GetTotal_Room(id_room_type As Int32) As Int32

    Dim Db As New HotelEntities

    Return (From I In Db.Room_Room Where I.ID_Room_Type = id_room_type).Count

End Function
```

> Message Error :LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32
>   GetTotal_Room(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to add a property to an EF entity without adding a corresponding column to the database table?

Comment: Yes exactly, its task is just to query

Comment: I am afraid your query which use `GetTotal_Room` function will not even compile. Introduce new type which you will create based on query result and use it for `DataGridView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem and I solved it by extracting the list first and then applying linq over it. You can try by altering your code as below.

```
Dim Db As New HotelEntities
Dim roomTypeList = Db.Room_Type.ToList()
Dim s = (From I In roomTypeList
         Select I.ID_Room_Type, I.Name_Room_Type,
         ColumnTemp = GetTotal_Room(I.ID_Room_Type)).ToList()

Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = s
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework will generate Linq query expressions to valid sql query.
As error message explain EF doesn't know how to convert your method `GetTotal_Room` to valid sql query.

Instead you can get required result from one query, without extra function.

```
From roomRoom In db.Room_Room
Join roomType In db.Room_Type On roomRoom.ID_Room_Type Equals roomType.ID_Room_Type
Select New With { roomRoom.ID_Room_Type, roomType.Name_Room_Type } Into roomtypes
Group roomtypes By roomtypes Into grouptypes
Select New With
{
   Id = grouptypes.Key.ID_Room_Type,
   Name = grouptypes.Key.Name_Room_Type,
   Total = grouptypes.Count()
}
```

As additional notice, I don't know context of your application, but based on given sample, I think you can remove some prefixes and suffixes in table and column names

```
RoomType
    Id
    Name

Room
    TypeId -- reference to RoomType.Id
```

Comment: Sory , Error Code

Comment: From what I can see, Fabio just mistyped `)` instead of `}`. Saying 'Error Code' doesn't help him to help you